# ExtJs: How to use plugin within defined component in MVC architecture?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Due to the lack of experience, I can't find how to activate an upload plugin in button component using MVC architecture.
When I used few files, this plugin works perfect. 
But when I started to move to MVC direction, everything begin to fall apart.

Here is how I initialize the plugin:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig( {
        enabled: true,
        paths: {
            'Ext.ux.upload': 'ext-4.2.1.883/src/ux/upload/'
        }
    });
Ext.require([
    ....
    'Ext.ux.upload.Button',
    'Ext.ux.upload.plugin.Window',
    .....
```

Here is the "old way" which worked perfect (button is situated on a panel, when you click it, the plugin upload window opens):

```
ObjectPhotosTab = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        disabled    : true,
        id          : 'ObjectPhotosTab',
        collapsible : true,
        frame       : true,
        title       : 'Photos',
        items       : [
            //here goes button with upload plugin
            Ext.create('Ext.ux.upload.Button', {
                text        : 'Select files',
                id          : 'ObjectPhotosUploadBtn',
                SelectedObjectId     : 0,
                autoRender  : true,
                hidden      : true,
                plugins: [{
                    ptype   : 'ux.upload.window',
                    title   : 'Upload',
                    width   : 320,
                    height  : 350,
                    pluginId: 'pid'
                }],
                uploader: {
                    url             : MainSiteUrl + 'getimages.php?a=a&Object=',
                    uploadpath      : '/Root/files',
                    autoStart       : true,
                    max_file_size   : '2020mb',
                    statusQueuedText: 'Ready to upload',
                    statusUploadingText: 'Uploading ({0}%)',
                    statusFailedText: '<span style="color: red">Error</span>',
                    statusDoneText: '<span style="color: green">Complete</span>',
                    statusInvalidSizeText: 'File too large',
                    statusInvalidExtensionText: 'Invalid file type'
                },
                listeners: {
                    filesadded: function(uploader, files) {
                        console.log('filesadded');
                        return true;
                    },
                    .......,
                    scope: this
                }
            }),
            Ext.getCmp('ImagesDataView') // other stuff

        ]
    });
```

In my new application I have moved an upload button to the "view" directory (surely through controller) and put plugin params to initComponent like this:

```
Ext.define('crm.view.ObjectPhotosUploadBtn',{
    extend: 'Ext.ux.upload.Button',
    text        : 'Select files',
    id          : 'ObjectPhotosUploadBtn',
    alias       : 'widget.ObjectPhotosUploadBtn',
    SelectedObjectId     : 0,
    autoRender  : true,
    hidden      : false,
    initComponent: function() {
        this.plugins = {
            ptype   : 'ux.upload.window',
            title   : 'Upload',
            width   : 320,
            height  : 350,
            pluginId: 'pid'
        };
        this.uploader ={
            // exactly the same stuff
        };
        this.listeners = {
            // exactly the same stuff
        };
        this.callParent();
    }
})
```

New defined button class is called from a panel like this:

```
   ObjectPhotosTab = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        disabled    : true,
        id          : 'ObjectPhotosTab',
        collapsible : true,
        frame       : true,
        title       : 'Photos',
        items       : [
            Ext.widget('ObjectPhotosUploadBtn'), // call button via widget
            Ext.getCmp('ImagesDataView') // other stuff

        ]
    });
```

Here is the header of file /ext-4.2.1.883/src/ux/upload/plugin/Window.js

```
/**@class Ext.ux.upload.plugin.Window
 * @extends Ext.AbstractPlugin
 * @author Harald Hanek (c) 2011-2012
 * @license http://harrydeluxe.mit-license.org*/

Ext.define('Ext.ux.upload.plugin.Window', {
    extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
    alias: 'plugin.ux.upload.window',
    requires: [ 'Ext.ux.statusbar.StatusBar',
                'Ext.ux.statusbar.ValidationStatus' ],
    constructor: function(config) {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, config);
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    init: function(cmp) {
        var me = this,
            uploader = cmp.uploader;
        cmp.on({
            filesadded: {
      ......
```

Here is the header of file /ext-4.2.1.883/src/ux/upload/Button.js

```
/**@class Ext.ux.upload.Button
 * @extends Ext.button.Button
 * @author Harald Hanek (c) 2011-2012
 * @license http://harrydeluxe.mit-license.org */
Ext.define('Ext.ux.upload.Button', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    alias: 'widget.uploadbutton',
    requires: ['Ext.ux.upload.Basic'],
    disabled: true,
    constructor: function(config) {
        var me = this;
        config = config || {};
        Ext.applyIf(config.uploader, {
            browse_button: config.id || Ext.id(me)
        });
        me.callParent([config]);
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this,
            e;
        me.callParent();
        me.uploader = me.createUploader();
    ......
```

The problem is that the button is created successfully but **it does not do needed plugin action**.

I see no errors in ff/chrome console also.

When I inspect "crm.view.ObjectPhotosUploadBtn" through the Illuminations ff plugin, I can see all needed plugin properties of this class.

Please help me to solve this question.

Answer (score -1):

There is too much code for me to quote, but the problem lies in this snippet:

```
Ext.define('crm.view.ObjectPhotosUploadBtn',{
    extend: 'Ext.ux.upload.Button',
    ...
    initComponent: function() {
        this.plugins = {
        ...
        };
    }
});
```

By the time `initComponent` is executed, the plugins have already been constructed and initialized in the constructor, and your `initComponent` overwrites all that.

What you need instead is to move the plugins blob into the class definition:

```
Ext.define('crm.view.ObjectPhotosUploadBtn', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.upload.Button',
    ...
    plugins: [{
        ptype   : 'ux.upload.window',
        title   : 'Upload',
        width   : 320,
        height  : 350,
        pluginId: 'pid'
    }]
});
```

The same goes for `uploader` and `listeners` assignments.

Comment: yes, initComponent seems to be redundant, but this is not the clue.